# Need to convert Date Time Format from JSON to 1 day ago or 3 mins ago in Java

Tags: java, android, datetime, retrofit2, android-viewholder

I need help converting time from the JSON array and displaying it on recycler view in the example published 3 mins ago. The JSON property is `"published_on": 1663222879`.

My JSON Response:

```json
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "id": "28035611",
      "guid": "https://coingape.com/?p=121674",
      "published_on": 1663222879,
      "imageurl": "https://images.cryptocompare.com/news/default/coingape.png",
      "lang": "EN",
      "source_info": {
        "name": "CoinGape",
        "lang": "EN",
        "img": "https://images.cryptocompare.com/news/default/coingape.png"
      }
    }
],
  "RateLimit": {},
  "HasWarning": false
}
```

My bindonviewHolder

```java
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(dataList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.body.setText(dataList.get(position).getBody());

    //Glide Library to display the images

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(dataList.get(position).getImageurl())
            .into(holder.imageViewUrl);
}
```

Comment: The 'published_on' appears to be a datestamp or unix epoch format (milliseconds since 1970) but a quick check using https://www.timecalculator.net/milliseconds-to-date indicates that the the date was 20/01/1970 16:00:22 pretty sure json was not around back then.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `published_on` represents Epoch seconds which can be converted into `Instant` using [`Instant#ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-).

Once you have the instance of `Instant`, you can subtract the desired amount of time and also convert the same Epoch seconds as shown below:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Convert the given epoch seconds into Instant
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1663222879);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Three minutes ago
        Instant threeMinsAgo = instant.minus(3, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.println(threeMinsAgo);
        long epochSecondThreeMinsAgo = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(threeMinsAgo.toEpochMilli(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println(epochSecondThreeMinsAgo);

        // One Day ago
        Instant oneDayAgo = instant.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println(oneDayAgo);
        long epochSecondOneDayAgo = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(oneDayAgo.toEpochMilli(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println(epochSecondOneDayAgo);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-09-15T06:21:19Z
2022-09-15T06:18:19Z
1663222699
2022-09-14T06:21:19Z
1663136479
```

Learn about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: thanks for letting me know that its Epoch Time, additionally  I wanted to know if there's a way I could place the converted value in recyclerView Holder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the date by 1 day back subtract 86400000 from 1665223725508 which is 08/10/2022 for 3 minutes subtract 180000

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having this issue, you can use Momentjs to convert time and date to any format you like.

For example:

`moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // will convert to 11 years ago`

Check the documentation on [Momentjs website](https://momentjs.com/)
NPM package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)